# C++ input with scanf

Tags: c++, input, console, scanf

I have problem with the console input. When I use `cin` it works perfectly but when I use `scanf` it doesn't work.
I deleted all the stuff that is not important and here is the program:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n;
char c, t;
char a[81][81];
int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0;j < n; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%c", a[i][j]);
        }
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0;j < n; ++j)
        {
            cout <<a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I test it with input like this:

```
2
t t t t
```

It should output:

```
t t t t
```

But instead it outputs this:

```
 t   t
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "it does not work" please be very specific: at the minimum, you should say what was your input, what was the expected output, and how did the actual output differ from it.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` O_O

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. The compiler should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I think the program is self-explainable what it needs to do. With any test it doesn't work.

Comment: Drop - "O_O" = what???

Comment: Always add to a question what you did, what happened and what you expected. I suspect that your assumption on what is supposed to happen might be wrong. But it's hard to tell from just seeing the source code.

Comment: If someone points out an error in your code and you see that it's only a typo on pasting the code here, please fix the error. You received answers on an error that actually is none. That's unfortunate. I tried to edit your file accordingly but the edit was refused. Not sure why ... ... Anyway. When you ask a question, it's your duty to maintain the question so it becomes a good reference for others. Do not just write down your question, wait for answers and then select a good one. You should be the one working hardest on receiving a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
```

and expect the value to be read into `c` since that function call works with a reference to a `char`. The function signature is equivalent to:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, char& c);
```

However,

```
char c;
scanf("%c", c);
```

does not work since `scanf` expects a pointer to a `char`. Hence, you must use;

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

What does it mean for your code? You must use:

```
scanf("%c", &a[i][j]);
```

Comment: This answer misses the fundamental problem that the op is experiencing - namely the automatic removal of whitespace by `operator>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
scanf("%c", &a[i][j]);
```

instead of this:

```
scanf("%c", a[i][j]);
```

**WHY?**

Well, `scanf` is supposed to perform a **write** on the variable(s) you pass (except the format string). In C, it was possible only through pointers. Hence you need to pass **address of** `a[i][j]`

Why does it work for `cin>>`? Well, C++ has introduced **references**, and `n` is passed as `int&` not just `int`. `cin` is of type `std::istream` (a class) having `operator>>` implemented. When you do:

```
cin >> n;
```

It is translated as:

```
cin.operator>>(n);
```

Where `n` is passed as `int&`

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental difference between `scanf("%c")` and `operator>>`

This program demonstrates it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "with operator >>" << std::endl;

    std::istringstream ss(" t t ");
    char c;
    while (ss >> c)
        std::cout << "[" << c << "]" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "with scanf" << std::endl;
    auto str = " t t ";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        char c;
        if (sscanf(str + i, "%c", &c)) {
            std::cout << "[" << c << "]" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
with operator >>
[t]
[t]
with scanf
[ ]
[t]
[ ]
[t]
[ ]
```

Notice that `operator>>` is removing whitespace (this is the default behaviour of a c++ `std::basic_istream<>`, and can be disabled).

Notice that `sscanf` is not removing whitespace for the `%c` operator.

From the documentation of %c:

> matches a character or a sequence of characters

As opposed to %s:

> matches a sequence of **non-whitespace** characters (a string)

A space is a character. It is also a whitespace character.

source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf